# Specifying server in remote CCTray for cruiseServerControl

Tags: cctray

When using a [cruiserServerControlAction](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/CruiseServer_Control_Task) in CCTray, how do you specify the remote server tag? The documentation only specifies that a string must be entered, I tried ip address with various leading and trailing slashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format, which doesn't seem to be documented anywhere (maybe it is obvious but it wasn't for me!) is:

```
tcp://{ipaddress}:{port}
```

I found this by looking through the source code and seeing the default value that was being used. If anyone is involved in the community, I guess the doc's could be updated to show the default value:

```
tcp://localhost:21234
```